# Given that f(n)>0 and constant c>0 Prove that f(n)+c = O(f(n)) or provide a counter-example if it's false

Tags: asymptotics

**Question:**

Given that f(n)>0 and c>0

Prove that f(n)+c  =  O(f(n)) or  provide a counter-example if it's false.

**My Effort to solve:** \begin{eqnarray*}
f(n) + c \space  \leq \space d\cdot&f(n)\space for \space all\space n \geq n_0\space and \space d>0\\
\end{eqnarray*}
So i believe there can be found some large d that satisfies this equation, but i am not sure about it.

Comment: @Complexity the problem is, this equation actually may be wrong and only true if f(n)>=1, but I don't know why.

Comment: Is $f(n)$ integer-valued?

Comment: Your "effort to solve" doesn't match the definition of Big-O.

Comment: @gnasher729 why?

Comment: @codemonkey Well, you changed it since my comment. And it's still misleading: You must show the inequality for _one_ fixed d > 0, and for _all_  n ≥ n0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. A counterexample is $f(n)=1/n$ and $c=1$.

If $f(n)+c=O(f(n))$, then there exists $n_0>0$ and $d>0$, for any $n>n_0$,  $f(n)+c\le df(n)$, or $1/n+1\le d/n$. But let $n=\max\{n_0+1,d\}$, the inequality fails obviously, a contradiction.

In fact, any $f(n)$ and $c$ such that $f(n)\to 0$ ($n\to\infty$) and $c>0$ are sufficient.

Comment: Why let n = max {n_0 + 1,d} ?

Comment: @codemonkey The intent is to make $n>n_0$ and $n>d-1$.